# How can I spoof my mac address on Bluestacks?

Tags: root-access, bluestacks, mac-address

My Bluestacks is rooted already with terminal installed. (Busybox 1.21.1)

Thus far, I have tried

1. Mac Address Ghost - App runs, but simply does spoof MAC
2. Xprivacy - xposed framework keeps getting seg faults upon installation
3. `# ip link set eth0 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx` - Operation not supported on transportation endpoint
4. `# busybox ifconfig eth0 hw ether 00:11:22:33:44:55` - Operation not supported

Has anyone achieved this before or know of a way to change the mac address of Bluestacks?

Answer (score 1):

Unzip `initrd.img` in `c:\programdata\android\` folder (by default). It's a GZIP format.

Next, you should edit `initrd` file with hex editor.
Find your address,
for example 
**02**C64001**00**C64002**00**C64003**62**C64004**73**C64005**74**

And Replace 02:00:00:64:73:74 bytes with your hex bytes (MAC ADDRESS)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rVumD8tmjg

Gzip initrd to initrd.img and replace original file

Comment: and how to change the Wifi MAC address using the above method?